# How to get arguments of function passed as parameter?

Tags: typescript

Given the following `TypeScript` function:

```
register(action: (customData: CustomClass) => void): number {
    // get the first argument
    action.arguments.??? // <-- how to access the arguments of the function passed in?
}
```

which is called like

```
someInstance.register(this.doStuff);
```

and having the `doStuff`-function defined as

```
doStuff = (customData: CustomClass): void => {
    console.log(customData.someValue);
}
```

The `doStuff` function has one parameter `customData` of type `CustomClass`.

How can this one be accessed inside the `register`-function (first one)?

Calling `action.arguments` inside is `null` and even in chromes dev.tools I can't figure out how to get access to it.

Comment: Action is a function. You need to pass an argument into it, there is nothing inside it. Arguments are accessible when they have been passed into functions that are invoked. In this instance 'action' is a function that hasn't been invoked. Besides arguments can be accessed only from within the function itself.

Answer (score 2):

You pass the function as first-class object, it hasn't real parameters during the passing it as argument of the "register" function. You should pass arguments later, then you will use (execute) this function:

```
class Test {
    _actions: Array<(customData: CustomClass) => void> = [];
    register(action: (customData: CustomClass) => void): void {
        this._actions.push(action);
    }
    executeActions(customData: CustomClass) {
        // execute all registered actions with passed customData
        this._actions.forEach(action => action(customData));
    }
}
```

#### Update 1. Full example

```
class CustomClass {
    constructor(public a: string = "abc") {}
}

class Test {
    _actions: Array<(customData: CustomClass) => void> = [];
    register(action: (customData: CustomClass) => void): void {
        this._actions.push(action);
    }
    executeActions(customData: CustomClass) {
        // execute all registered actions with passed customData
        this._actions.forEach(action => action(customData));
    }
}

var test = new Test();
var action = (customData: CustomClass) => {
    console.log(customData.a);
}

test.register(action);

test.executeActions(new CustomClass());
```